# Не проксируется соединение FireFox+Selenium

Tags: java, firefox, proxy, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Здравствуйте.
Связка java+selenium-webdriver.
Инициализация драйвера и прокси:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy("62.122.100.90:8080");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Потом пробую открыть 2ip, чтобы проверить, проксируется ли соединение:

```
driver.get(sAdress);
```

IP-адрес определяется родной.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда "копать"?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();` нужно использовать

Comment: Спасибо, попробую - отпишусь.

Comment: поменял на `capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().firefox()` - не работает, тот же родной ip-адрес

Comment: Разобрался. Открыл браузер командой firefox -p, настроил прокси-сервер в профиле "default". В коде указал какой профиль подгружать: `FirefoxProfile profile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile("default");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);`